# 'maven package' command not picking up externalized .properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, application.properties

I'm building a backend servie using spring boot. The packaging type is war.
I externalized the main application config, including RSA private keys in a file named `env.properties` located at the project root folder(right next to pom.xml).
In the main `application.properties` file, I have all the same fields that reference the fields in the `env.properties` file.
I put `application.properties` in version control, not the `env.properties`.

My purpose of doing so is that I can keep the real production config away from version control and make each delopyment flexible in terms of configuration.

During development, the setup works fine, but the problem comes when I try to deploy the application. After running mvn clean build, I get a .war file, which won't start (404) when I deploy it on tomcat9.
If I try to run the .war file with java -jar xxx.war, the output is

```
$ java -jar xxx.war
23:04:12.260 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter - Application failed to start due to an exception
org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataResourceNotFoundException: Config data resource 'file [env.properties]' via location 'file:env.properties' cannot be found
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataResourceNotFoundException.withLocation(ConfigDataResourceNotFoundException.java:97)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.handle(ConfigDataImporter.java:145)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.load(ConfigDataImporter.java:136)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.resolveAndLoad(ConfigDataImporter.java:86)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentContributors.withProcessedImports(ConfigDataEnvironmentContributors.java:116)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.processInitial(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:240)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.processAndApply(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:227)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:102)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:94)
        at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:102)
        at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:87)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:85)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:66)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:120)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:114)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:65)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:339)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:297)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301)
        at com.jnairport.yqpay.YqpayApplication.main(YqpayApplication.java:10)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:59)
23:04:12.267 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter - 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Config data resource 'file [env.properties]' via location 'file:env.properties' does not exist

Action:

Check that the value 'file:env.properties' at class path resource [application.properties] - 1:22 is correct, or prefix it with 'optional:'
```

It seems when I package the application for deployment, maven didn't pick up the `env.properties` file. The whole app won't run at all.

I've tried to search for solutions but got no clue.
Please help, thanks.

Comment: I think the best way to solve this would be spring cloud config server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reply from Jakub Marchwicki, it's quite detailed. I believe it's going to help a lot of people who may have searched for a similar issue in the future.

I solved the problem by ditching the whole idea of using the env.properties file for externalized config. After some study I found a better way of using spring profiles, where I keep config files for different profiles and reference the needed one in application.properties file.

For example, I could have a `application-development.properties` file and a `application-production.properties` file. When in development, the first config file is referenced in the main `application.properties` file whereas in production, the second one is referenced. The config file for production is not version controlled of course.

You may find this article useful: https://springframework.guru/spring-profiles/

Hope it helps, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I sense two issues (writing sense as it's hard to be sure without a reproducible example):

- referencing a file by `file:env.properties` is error-prone, as this path is different on every system
- maven doesn't know about the `env.properties` file and there for it doesn't include it in the package

Let's tackle that one by one

### Resource location

Your reference `file:env.properties` is ambiguous. When you define your resource location with `file` it uses `FileSystemResource` underneath. See spring documentation on [`FileSystemResource` Caveats](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#resources-filesystemresource-caveats).

So when you write your test, your IDE looks for a project root path. But when you are running the jar file - the path might be different. That might be the reason why app is unable to find a properties file.

Probably the best approach would be to pack the `env.properties` into the war file during the build process or (even better) set the values in the properties file as [environment variables](https://12factor.net/config)

### Packaging with Maven

You can include your `env.properties` in your application classpath, without versioning it. That way you can refer to the file with `classpath:env.properties` within your application codebase

You will need to extend your Maven build file with [additional resource location](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html)